# Parameterized Discriminated Union in F#

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typed abstract syntax tree with function application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552759/typed-abstract-syntax-tree-with-function-application)

I would like to have the following

```
type t<'a>=
  | Val of 'a
  | Apply of (('a -> 'b) -> t<'a> -> t<'b>) * t<'a>
  | Apply2 of (('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> t<'a> -> t<'b> -> t<'c>)* t<'a> * t<'b>
```

That is, `Apply` takes a function and a t, and applies f to the "content" of `t`.

However it asks to have `t<'a, 'b, 'c>`, which means I then have to use three parameters for all `t<_>`. Is there a way to circumvent it?

Many thanks for your insights

Comment: May be duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552759/typed-abstract-syntax-tree-with-function-application

Comment: Indeed. I had missed it ! Thanks a lot.